# How to select and change background of a UICollectionCell in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to have a UIcollectionCell #20 selected and change the color in viewWillAppear.  Here is my code in viewWillAppear.

```
[self.periodCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:20 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];

selectedCell = (ViewPeriodCollectionCell *)[self.periodCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:20 inSection:0]];

[selectedCell setButtonSelected:YES];
```

This works fine in `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I would put some break points in your collection view `dataSource` methods and another in your code above in `viewWillAppear` to see if the table is being reloaded after you set the selection which could possibly wipe out your selection status depending on how you set up your cells.

Comment: Problem solved! All I had to do was put them in ViewDidAppear.  =)